# usbfs driver in kernel source

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, libusb

usbfs_driver structure was initialized at https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/usb/core/devio.c#L748 as shown below.

```
struct usb_driver usbfs_driver = {
   .name =     "usbfs",
   .probe = driver_probe,
   .disconnect =  driver_disconnect,
   .suspend =  driver_suspend,
   .resume =   driver_resume,
   .supports_autosuspend = 1,
};
```

All functions used to initialize the above structure are dummy functions.

As per comment before driver_probe(https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/usb/core/devio.c#L683),
user space driver will take care of claiming the interface. But user space drivers also needs device file to access the device, Will the usbfs driver creates the device files for each connected device.

What is the use of this usbfs driver in the USB subsystem?

Comment: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/usb/proc_usb_info.txt: *In many modern systems the usbfs filesystem isn't used at all.*

Comment: Then how user space drivers will access usb devices? i.e who will create device files for a usb device for which driver is not available in kernel space.

Comment: `libusb` has other ways to access USB devices that do not involve the deprecated usbfs. Namely, it can use `libudev` to access the USB devices under `/dev/bus/usb/`.